# Исключить ненужные значения при поиске

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется рабочий код, который получает html-данные с помощью ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/testers',
    success: res => {
        let data = $(res).find('.col-heading');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Дело в том, что он находит все вхождения, а мне нужно только те, в которых присутствует атрибут `placeholder`. Возможно ли это как-то сделать прямо в поиске? Или нужно будет делать какую-то фильтрацию после?

Comment: `.find('.col-heading[placeholder]')`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, большое спасибо, не думал что все так просто может оказаться. Можете оформить как ответ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```
let data = $(res).find('.col-heading[placeholder]')
```